# Which verb do you use to refer to an email conversation?

Tags: word-choice

When you are having a conversation with someone through emails, are you "speaking | talking | chatting | ... "?

Comment: try *corresponding*, since it is medium neutral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are [emailing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e-mail#Verb), [mailing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mail#Verb), [corresponding](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/correspond) per email, or [exchanging](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exchange) emails.

Comment: I want to write something like "Nice to have -exchanged?- with you during this time". Is it right?

Comment: 'Chatted' would sound more natural if that was the register you were using - words regularly expand their meaning, and it's obvious what is meant. It would be unwieldy to have a word meaning 'communicate by email in a chatty register' etc.

Comment: I wouldn't use _exchanged_ by itself like that, although you could say "Nice to have _exchanged emails_ with you." This might be a more suitable question for ELL.SE though, the Stack Exchange for [ELL.SE].