# 'Emailed' as a verb (vs 'sent email')

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I've started to see '**emailed**' a lot in our company correspondence but as a non-native speaker I always tend to use '**sent email**' instead. Here are some examples from reliable sources:

> “I worked with a lady in England named Elizabeth; she’s the best namer of horses I’ve ever met,” Mr. Roberts said. “So I **emailed** her and asked what I would name him. She **emailed** right back. She didn’t say ‘I suggest,’ or ‘I think.’” She said, “His name is Benediction.”
> -- New York Times

> “We condemn the use of the death penalty in all its forms. The death penalty is an inhuman, cruel and irreversible punishment that has no place in modern law,” Swedish Foreign Minister Margot Wallstrom said in an **emailed** comment to Reuters news agency. -- Independent

Can we use '**email**' as a verb as it is? How normal is this?

According to my own research, '**emailed**' has been used a lot but '**email**' as a verb is not common. So is this an exception just for the past tense?

*Emailed* - [Lengusa](https://lengusa.com/search/emailed)

*Email them* - [Lengusa](https://lengusa.com/search/email%20them) (replace them with him/her etc)

Comment: Utterly normal. In fact, _email_ is rather obsolete, since so many other verbable services are available. English can use just about any [noun as a verb, with different meanings](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Verbing.pdf).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which verb do you use to refer to an email conversation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/which-verb-do-you-use-to-refer-to-an-email-conversation)

Comment: That is about the usage of the word. I also know that it's a legitimate word. I am just trying to understand how normal it is.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yeah, [ is obsolete or even dead](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558646/emailed-as-a-verb-vs-sent-email#comment1378611_558649), or at least should be.

Comment: @JohnLawler  What's _really_ obsolete, I have been told,  is a hyphen: _e-mail_.

Comment: Like *_i-Phone_ or *_i-Mac_.

Comment: @JohnLawler How does that make it "obsolete"

Answer (score 8):

Yes, *email* can be a verb. Just as you can *send mail* or *mail* something in English, you can *send an email* or *email* something.

According to the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com/view/Entry/240904), *email* as a verb goes back at least to the 1980s:

> 1983   Computokid in net.micro (Usenet newsgroup) 25 Aug.   Young stuff interested in correspondence (via dull old paper mail) might **email** a letter to me to forward.

By the 1990s, *email* was understandable enough to use in an advertisement to UNIX users:

> 1993   UNIX Rev. Mar. 28/3 (advt.)    Call, fax or **email** for a free demo.

It's hard to overstate how commonly understood the usage is. As a small illustration, here are four members of the United States Congress ([1](https://ocasio-cortez.house.gov/contact),[2](https://langevin.house.gov/contact-me/email-me),[3](https://www.tillis.senate.gov/email-me),[4](https://www.blackburn.senate.gov/email-me)) using *email me* in the title of a site about contacting them via email.

Comment: Sometimes I *mail* people ”things”, no matter whether those “things” are observations or  notes or quotes or citations or letters or messages or approvals or questions. And sometimes I just *send* them those things. But I don’t usually *note* them observations let alone *question* them notes or vice versa. But I imagine I may sometimes *message* them an exciting confirmation. I find messaging people “an” xcitement to be nearly as hard as sending them citations. Have you ever been sent an quote full of words? Honestly  is as dead as cigarettes and typewriters, or should be.

Comment: @tchrist Hah, maybe it should die. I think *email* clings on where many other *e*-terms have died out because it was adopted so early and persists as a common form of exchange. It also eliminates ambiguity: "I'll send it to you" could occur in multiple formats, but "I'll email you" or "I'll Venmo you" is more specific and brief about what to expect. (I'm not endorsing the use of Venmo, Paypal, or other platforms as a verb, but they have been effectively verbed at the moment, instead of a possible verb like e-transfer.)

Comment: The verb *post* is another one that sees ambiguous usage. If tell me that you posted your survey response, did you mean that you sent that via "the post(s)" (*read:* the physical postal service with a real postbox and a real postman etc),  or did you just electronically publish it somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: You can always verb a noun and have it take root, but when the noun has left the building? cf. *Fax it, telex it, telegraph it*...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, email is very much used as a verb, especially by native speakers, I have noticed that as well. [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=email_VERB%2C%20send%20an%20email&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cemail_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csend%20an%20email%3B%2Cc0) is very clear about it:

[image]

Note that it can be used both transitively (send *something* by email)

> [ + two objects ] Has he emailed you that list of addresses yet?
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/email)]

and intransitively:

> : **to communicate by email**
>
> As I write this, a colleague who takes an amateur interest in tracking the weather emailed to say it would be "among the hottest days of 2019 so far, if not #1".
>
> [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/email)]